# test shelllist if selected is file, folder or blank

Tags: delphi

Me again with another question.

I am using a shelllist from raize and want to add some code to the on click event to test if the selected item is valid (file, folder or blank) but I am unsure how to correctly do this.

Here is what I have.

```
procedure ZipCheck;
var
  Path : string;
  i : integer;
  s : string;
  DecompStream : TMemoryStream;
  LExtention : string;
begin

  Path := form2.FileList.SelectedItem.PathName;
  form2.FNameEdit.Text := Path;

  if form2.FileList.SelectedItem.IsValid = true then
  begin
    LExtention :=  TPath.GetExtension(form2.filelist.SelectedItem.PathName);
    if tpath.GetExtension(LExtention) = '.zip' then
    begin
      Showmessage(LExtention);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

What happens is when I click on a blank area of the shelllist I get an exception error.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `SelectedItem` is not nil before you try to access any of its members.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I talked to guys a raize and he suggested that I do the following. if filelist.selecteditem = nil then begin exit; end;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want ZipCheck to function as a event handler for the on click. This will not work, because an event handler must be a method (procedure in a class) with the correct parameters.

An added advantage is that you don't need to access the form var (form2).

So you get:

```
   procedure TForm2.ZipCheck(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Path : string;
      i : integer;
      s : string;
      DecompStream : TMemoryStream;
      LExtention : string;
    begin

      Path := FileList.SelectedItem.PathName;
      FNameEdit.Text := Path;

      if FileList.SelectedItem.IsValid = true then
      begin
        LExtention :=  TPath.GetExtension(filelist.SelectedItem.PathName);
        if tpath.GetExtension(LExtention) = '.zip' then
        begin
          Showmessage(LExtention);
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: I tried the change but still have the same problem when clicking on an empty space in the shelllist. I have tried this on the form and in a unit. I am curious if maybe the syntax "selecteditem.isvalid" may not be what I should be using?